# Will ASIFormDataRequest still work when my SSL certificate expires?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, asihttprequest

I'm using the `ASIFormDataRequest` class from the [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to talk to a .NET web service over an HTTPS connection.

I'd like to make a solution that eliminates the need for SSL security, but the SSL certificate expires sooner than I can get an update to the AppStore.

I'm wondering what will happen when the app makes an `ASIFormDataRequest` after the certificate has expired. Will an error be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If certificate checking is enabled (which is the default) then any requests to a server with an expired ssl certificate will fail with an error.

Comment: Thanks, this can be controlled with the `setValidatesSecureCertificate` property.